# Use Google place autocomplete web service with Latitude & Longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I want to use Google place autocomplete webservice: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

to search for locations based upon a query (e.g. "High Street"). I also want the latitude and longitude of each place.

It seems that the only way to do this using the web service is to:

1. Perform an autocomplete search e.g.

   > https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=(cities)&language=en_GB&key=YOUR_API_KEY
2. Loop through each result and do a separate query for each location (see https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details):

   > https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=PLACE_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY

That means if I have 10 results, I have to do 10 additional web requests! That means 11 in total (1 for autocomplete, and 10 more for each place request).

This is very inefficient!

Surely there is a better way than this, as Google Maps on Android shows the distance of each place to your current location, indicating that the latitude and longitude is returned as shown by this screenshot:

[image: Android Google Maps Search]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro), [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) and [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) that is the case. There is no other way.

Comment: So how does the Google Maps Android app do it? Try using their autocomplete and you'll see they also show how many miles you are from that location.

Comment: @YahyaUddin https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start#api-overview looks like the same procedure, can you point where does it say that you can do that in android? or an example showing that you can actually get the coordinates from autocomplete in android.

Comment: @betofarina Updated question

Comment: one thing is that autocomplete shows you some info(distance in this case), and another is that the API is intended to give you lat,lng . Understand that because google shows you something does not mean that google is willing to let you have it so easily.

Comment: anyway good luck in your search, personally ill suggest you to have this answer as the answer if you want to save time ;)

Comment: Yeah I think your right. Might leave it open for a bit though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this API
of google APIs
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Winnetka&key=YOUR_API_KEY